Is it a bad idea to use NodeJS + Python for back end development?
I'm working on a platform that consumes and transforms data to make reports and visualize those reports in a client app.
The team has experience with NodeJS and NestJS, and some of us have experience with Python.
We need the visualization platform to be stable and scalable, and most importantly, quick.
As we need to do light ETL processes, and our team's experience leans towards Node, I was wondering if it would be a good idea to have a different service/API in Python to process the data, and use NestJS to deliver this data to the client (as well as handling authentication, authorization, etc).
Also, in the near future we also want to implement a microservices architecture, and I don't know how this idea would impact us.
The alternative that some proposed is to build the platform entirely on Python (FastApi).
I would love to hear your thoughts on this.


The team has experience with NodeJS and NestJS, and some of us have
experience with Python

Your choice is made for you. Even if you should really use a proper language like c#, are you really all going to zoom off a retrain because of some tiny arguable benefits? You have to use the tools in your tool box.

Can't upvote because I'm new, but thanks!!

Even if you should really use a proper language like c# What makes C# a proper language and what makes NodeJS or Python not a proper language?
